# Ace editor deletion is not happening properly while integrated with angular 12

Tags: angular, ace-editor

Ace editor deletion is not happening properly while integrated with angular 12
Like I put my cursor at the end of text and click on backspace instead of deleting that text it was deleting text from 4th or or some other position.

Comment: Provide code snippets to help people help you. This is an open invalid question. Provide specs.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with non-monospace fonts. Does it delete wrong character if you use end key to put cursor at the end of the line?